# Xcode iOS Simulator: can I use the mouse as pretend Apple Pencil input (on iPad Pro), for testing?

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios-simulator, stylus-pen

Is it possible to do this (with a menu, a shortcut, or a modifier key + mouse)?

For example, you can use the mouse to test simple touch gestures in the simulator, like left mouse acts as single finger, and shift / option allow for different two finger gestures.

I have been unable to find any documentation one way or the other about whether this is possible, despite [this developer.apple.com page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9_1.html) where the simple, easy-to-understand API changes for supporting Apple Pencil hardware are documented.

Do I need a physical iPad Pro + Pencil hardware to test my Pencil support?

(My app is not a drawing app, just an app where touch input should work with large touch targets and Pencil should allow finer distinctions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**iOS 14**

```swift
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
canvasView.drawingPolicy = .anyInput
#else
canvasView.drawingPolicy = .pencilOnly
#endif
```

Also in the Settings app there is a global setting called "Only Draw with Apple Pencil". This can be read from `UIPencilInteraction.prefersPencilOnlyDrawing` in PencilKit.

**iOS 13 (only)**

```swift
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
canvasView.allowsFingerDrawing = true
#else
canvasView.allowsFingerDrawing = false
#endif
```

Courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/62567169/2667933

Comment: This will work for some but not all of Apple Pencil features, i.e., only the ones that are shared with finger touches. Things like azimuth will not be available with this method. Having said that, it's a good solution for many applications.

Answer (score 6):

The Simulator does not currently support simulating Apple Pencil input. We are aware people would like to do this.

Comment: Why is it possible to use the Xamarin iOS remote simulator **with** support for pencil? See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451739

Comment: I can't comment on third-party products.

Comment: Do you mean, you are not allowed to, or you are not able to?