# Simulating Apple pencil in the simulator seems to be possible somehow

Tags: ios, xamarin, ios-simulator, stylus-pen

I was wondering if it is possible to simulate the Apple pencil in the iOS simulator.

According to an Apple emloyee here [Xcode iOS Simulator: can I use the mouse as pretend Apple Pencil input (on iPad Pro), for testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44639153) it is not possible. And the answer was given in June 2017.

According to https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/ (very last paragraph: *Stylus support in Windows is also translated to Apple Pencil input on the simulator.*), using the remote iOS simulator from Xamarin, it is possible to simulate the pencil. (and they have had this feature for some months already)

So, I am a bit confused. As far as I know, Xamarin uses the normal iOS simulator, too. (They just show it via a remote connection on a Windows PC) If they have pencil support in the simulator, it must be possible for anybody, mustn't it?

Comment: You can use the UI Automation framework (via the Instruments interface) to synthesize things like a UITouch while adding Pencil coalesced touches, etc... the issue of course is there is no touch screen/stylus Macs to collect the needed data from... I've seen a Wacom pad that was interfaced to a custom Appium IOS driver that allowed Pencil support for the iOS sim (this was mainly being used to collect Pencil data for Appium UI testing) but could be used as a poor-mans iPad Pro/Pencil combo.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you! I will take a look at UI Automation framework.

Answer (score 2):

For those who stuck with this in 2021 try the following:

**iOS 14**

```swift
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
canvasView.drawingPolicy = .anyInput
#else
canvasView.drawingPolicy = .pencilOnly
#endif
```

Also in the Settings app there is a global setting called "Only Draw with Apple Pencil". This can be read from `UIPencilInteraction.prefersPencilOnlyDrawing` in PencilKit.

**iOS 13 (only)**

```swift
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
canvasView.allowsFingerDrawing = true
#else
canvasView.allowsFingerDrawing = false
#endif
```

Courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/62567169/2667933