# iOS PencilKit not drawing

Tags: ios, swift, pencilkit

I am trying to PencilKit and but I cannot draw anything in the app.
I set my code as below.

```
import UIKit
import PencilKit

class DrawingViewController: UIViewController {

  var canvasView: PKCanvasView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let canvasView = PKCanvasView(frame: view.bounds)
    canvasView.allowsFingerDrawing = false
    view.addSubview(canvasView)

    canvasView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    canvasView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    canvasView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    canvasView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    canvasView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true

    canvasView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    canvasView.tool = PKInkingTool(.pen, color: .black, width: 10)
  }

}
```

I am expecting to draw / inking in the canvasView but there's no response when I try the app. My device is running in 13.2 so there's no problem with the target. I've also downloaded the [Apple's app from WWDC 2019](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/drawing_with_pencilkit) session but it's not working in the simulator. 
  For clarify I've also tested it in real device but not respond in any application with **PencilKit**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `canvasView.allowsFingerDrawing = false` may have been the problem if using a finger or mouse as input rather than an Apple pencil. Apple pencil does not currently work with iPhones if trying that combination. The code looks fine otherwise.

---

These are the iOS settings for drawing with PencilKit

**iOS 14**

Use the drawingPolicy setting to enable drawing by input type

Apple pencil only:

```
canvasView.drawingPolicy = .pencilOnly
```

Finger, mouse cursor(iOS simulator) and Apple pencil:

```
canvasView.drawingPolicy = .anyInput
```

Allows the user to set the desired input with Pencil Kit's toolpicker toggle:

```
canvasView.drawingPolicy = .default
```

In the Settings app there is a global setting called "Only Draw with Apple Pencil". This can be read from `UIPencilInteraction.prefersPencilOnlyDrawing` in PencilKit.

---

**iOS 13 (deprecated in iOS14)**

To draw with the Apple pencil only:

```
canvasView.allowsFingerDrawing = false
```

To draw with all input types:

```
canvasView.allowsFingerDrawing = true
```